# Best exception to throw inside a set method

Tags: java, exception

If I have a set method in which I want to modify some values,
if an user enter wrong values which is the best exception to throw to indicate that failure?

```
public void setSomething(int d) throws ....
{
    if (d < 10 && d >= 0)
    {
        // ok do something
    }
    else throw new ... // throw some exception
}
```

Comment: In this context, Daniel's answer is correct. However, in general, `IllegalArgumentException` is the appropriate exception to use, when it doesn't involve numerical ranges.

Comment: (I still maintain Daniel's answer is correct, except that we use the Java class `IndexOutOfBoundsException` instead of the .NET `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`. <rchern>Details schmetails!</rchern>)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

I'd go for [IllegalArgumentException](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/IllegalArgumentException.html).

> Thrown to indicate that a method has been passed an illegal or
>   inappropriate argument.

**EDIT**

Another note:

Instead of

```
if (conditionIsTrue) {
  doThis();
  doThat();
} else { 
  throw new IllegalArgumentException();
}
```

write:

```
if (conditionNotTrue) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException();
}

doThis();
doThat();
```

(Though this advice may be controversial ;-)).

Comment: +1 for the 'Another note' - this form is called a [guard clause](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?GuardClause). Personally, i would even dispense with the curly brackets in it, and make it a one-liner.

Comment: [The power of Jeff Atwood compels you!](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2006/01/flattening-arrow-code.html)

Answer (score 10):

I agree with @Code Monkey about creating your own InvalidArgumentException, but his implementation doesn't show all the advantages it provides.

1) You can add convenience methods to simplify argument checking. For example:

```
InvalidArgumentException.throwIfNullOrBlank(someString, "someString");
```

vs.

```
if (someString == null || someString.trim().isEmpty()) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("someString is null or blank");
}
```

2) You can write unit tests that confirm which argument was invalid. If you throw IllegalArgumentException, your unit test can't confirm that it was thrown for the reason you expect it to be thrown. You can't even tell that it was thrown by your own code.

```
try {
    someClass.someMethod(someValue);
    Assert.fail("Should have thrown an InvalidArgumentException");
} catch (InvalidArgumentException e) {
    Assert.assertEquals("someValue", e.getArgumentName());
}
```

3) You can tell that the exception was thrown from within your own code. (This is a minor point that doesn't have much practical advantage)

Comment: +1 for the testability. The point about convenience methods seems weak, since you could write a convenience method like that and throw a plain IllegalArgumentException from it.

Comment: +1 Yes, in this particular usage, I can understand creating your own value-added subclass (of `IllegalArgumentException`, not `Exception`---I absolutely detest inappropriate use of checked exceptions).

Comment: @Tom Yes, you certainly could. I think they're all weak arguments actually but I don't see any strong case for IllegalArgumentException either.

Answer (score 6):

If the number is an index, you could use [IndexOutOfBoundsException](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/IndexOutOfBoundsException.html). Otherwise, as Oliver says, [IllegalArgumentException](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/IllegalArgumentException.html).

Don't be afraid to create a subclass of IllegalArgumentException to be more precise about the problem. Any catch blocks written for IllegalArgumentException will still catch it, but the stack trace will be slightly more informative.